# Render Html code with razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've searched over this website and I've looked over similar questions and i did not find the answer, I am sure it is somewhere but i did not find it, I have a string like this one for example :

```
string inputText = "&lt;strong&gt;Hello World&lt;/strong&gt;"
```

This string comes from a certain request in control, and i have no power to change the model or the control. I can only change my razor view, using Html.Raw displays this result :

```
<strong>Hello World</strong>
```

And the result i want to be displayed is this one :

**Hello World**

How is it possible ?

PS: this is only a simple example, it can be any HTML Code.

Comment: Thanks but it did not work for me, but this one worked :) : @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(inputText))

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(inputText))
```

Decode and then render in html

Comment: I've edited this post, please learn how to do this on your own in future :)

Comment: What happens if the html contains custom html helpers like <strong>@ABC("test")</strong>? Which would work if placed directly in a cshtml file. But inside a string?

Answer (score 9):

To render any string (which includes HTML tags) -received from the model- as HTML, use:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.SomeString)
```